# События javascript и Deferred & setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

После выполнения обещаний (выполняются 7 сек) jQuery возбуждает событие.

```
    $.when(deferredActionsDone).done(function() {
        $(document).trigger('done');
    });
```

Вот так работает:

```
    $(document).on('done', function() {
        alert('deferred actions done!');
    });
```

Вот так не работает) Подскажите куда копать, как заставить работать)

```
   setTimeout(function() {
        $(document).on('done', function() {
            alert('deferred actions done!');
        });
   }, 15000);
```

Comment: во втором случае вы через 15 секунд устанавливаете обработчик на "done". А событие done видимо успевает придти до истечения этих 15 сек. Если обработчика на момент вызова trigger нет, то это событие нигде не сохранится и позже вызвано не будет

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

может попробовать поставить просто задержку на вывод сообщения:

```
        $(document).on('done', function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                alert('deferred actions done!');
            }, 15000);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function() {
     $(document).on("done", function() {
         alert("deferred actions done!")
     });
     deferredActionsDone.state() == "resolved" && $(document).trigger("done")
 }, 15000);
```